# Enterprise Architect : how to combine multiple generalization lines as a one single line

Tags: uml, class-diagram, enterprise-architect

Im using Enterprise Architect to design a class diagram.I have 4 child classes for one parent.
How can i make their multiple generalization lines as a one single line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply by manually arranging them to overlap. You need to eventually add bends by ctrl-clicking lines. EA usually has some smart placing of connectors so it's not too hard to get a match. There's also a tree-style in the context which might be usefull in this case:

[image]

P.S. As [@Geert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2018133/geert-bellekens) commented, there's the menu `Start | Desktop | Preferences | Links | General | Generalization link style default = Tree`. With a grain of salt though since menu positions keep floating from one EA version to another. He's likely referring 15.2. In 13.5 it's somewhere else. I could not find it directly but typing `Preferences` in the Start search window brought up the right window.

Comment: Worth mentioniong: there's also a setting to set the Tree Style as default for Generalization. See **Start | Desktop | Preferences | Links | General | Generalization link style default = Tree**